# java.lang.IllegalStateException not getting mapped by ExceptionMapper<Exception>

Tags: rest, kotlin, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to create an exception mapper for this java.lang.IllegalStateException. If I  throw java.lang.IllegalStateException("Incorrect State") , then It is not getting mapped to this DefaultExceptionMapper ExceptionMapper. Any ideas why this is happening?

````
```@Provider
    internal class DefaultExceptionMapper : ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
        override fun toResponse(e: Exception): Response {
            logger.error("Failed request DefaultExceptionMapper", e)
             return Response.serverError()
                        .entity(ProductServiceError(e.message, e))
                        .build()
            }
     }
````

The ExceptionMapper is from javax.rs.ws library :
package javax.ws.rs.ext;

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public interface ExceptionMapper<E extends Throwable> {
    Response toResponse(E var1);
}
```

Comment: `ExceptionMapper` isn't in the standard library, so I'm guessing it's from some framework or library.  You might get more interest if you mention it (especially in a tag).  Also presumably you have to register or inject or install your mapper somehow (depending on the library or framework) — it might help if you could show that.

Comment: @gidds Thanks for your reply. I have included the information about the javax.rs.ws library from which this ExceptionMapper is coming.